Hibernate problem in Oracle handling edge Double values
I'm testing the handling of basic Java values with Hibernate and Oracle. I have an Oracle table with a binary_double column, and I want to insert from Java the value Double.MAX_VALUE, which happens to be the literal 1.7976931348623157E308.
My Entity class has just two fields, with an id assigned manually:
@Entity
@Table(name="T_TYPES_NUMBERS")
public class TypesNumbersEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID", updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="DOUBLE_VALUE", columnDefinition="binary_double")
    private Double doubleValue;

    // setters, getters, etc.
}

In a test unit I create an instance of the entity class and assign Double.MAX_VALUE to the field. When I persist the entity and commit the transaction, the operation fails with an Oracle error:
ORA-01426: numeric overflow
When I try the insert from SQL Developer, the insert fails with the same error:
insert into t_types_numbers (id, double_value ) values (1003, 1.7976931348623155E308 );

SQL Error: ORA-01426: numeric overflow 01426. 00000 -  "numeric overflow"

The insert succeeds in SQL Developer with any one of these statements (a 'd' appended to the literal, or using a cast function):
insert into t_types_numbers (id, double_value )
values (1003, 1.7976931348623155E308d );

or
insert into t_types_numbers (main_id, double_value )
values (1004, to_binary_double('1.7976931348623155E308') );

So I changed the Entity class attribute to this (trying to use the to_binary_double function):
@Column(name="DOUBLE_VALUE", columnDefinition="binary_double")

@org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnTransformer(write="to_binary_double('?')")

private Double doubleValue;

But when I run the test case, I got these in the log file:
insert  into T_TYPES_NUMBERS (DOUBLE_VALUE, MAIN_ID)
values (to_binary_double('?'), ?)

TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [DOUBLE] - [3.141516]

TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1002]

WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 17003, SQLState: 99999

ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid column index

So, what's the proper way to handle an Oracle's binary_double column from Hibernate, to cover edge values as the maximum (or minimum) values, positive and negative from Java?
I am using Oracle 18c, Hibernate 5.4.33, and Oracle's JDBC driver 18.15.0.0.

It's a bug in Hibernate: their query generator should add the 'd' when handling binary_double, without it the range of acceptable values is the range of ... binary_float.

The problem being that the type is actually in the columnDefinition annotation, it will be much faster to create your own UserType than waiting for a fix...

A UserType must be written, so that you (the programmer) can handle directly the assignment and reading of values of type double or Double at a JDBC level.
You will also need an auxiliary class wrapping a double value. For example:
public class BinaryDouble {
    
        protected double value;
    
        public BinaryDouble(double value) { ... }
    
        /* only getter, no setter. */
        public double getValue() { return value; }
    
        /* add hashCode(), equals(Object obj) and toString() */
    
    }

The UserUtil implementation will use the BinaryDouble class (this is with Hibernate 5.4. In Hibernate 6 UserType is generic and would accept BinaryDouble as argument):
public class BinaryDoubleType implements UserType {

    /* UserType requires many methods to be implemented, which describe the type. */
    /* Here, only the specific ones that read and write a value are shown: */

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(
            PreparedStatement st,
            Object value, /* expected to be a BinaryDouble instance. */
            int index,
            SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException
    {

        /* Since Oracle is being used, the standard PreparedStatement can be */
        /*  cast to an Oracle-specific OraclePreparedStatement. */
        oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement ops = 
            (oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement) st;

        /* this method has to deal with nulls: */
        if (value == null) {
            ops.setNull(index, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.BINARY_DOUBLE);
        }
        else {
            double doubleValue = ((BinaryDouble) value).getValue();
            oracle.sql.BINARY_DOUBLE oracleDoubleValue = 
                new oracle.sql.BINARY_DOUBLE(doubleValue);
            ops.setBinaryDouble(index, oracleDoubleValue);
        }
    }

    /* This method will return a BinaryDouble instance, or null: */
    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(
            ResultSet rs,
            String[] names,
            SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
            Object owner)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException
    {
        /* No need to cast the ResultSet parameter to any Oracle specific class. */
        /* Reading the result set value as a standard double: */
        double doubleValue = rs.getDouble(names[0]);
        if (rs.wasNull()) {
            return null;
        }
        /* Return a new BinaryDouble instance wrapping the scalar double: */
        return new BinaryDouble(doubleValue);
    }

}

Finally, in any Entity which has a mapped double or Double field, change it to be of type BinaryDouble, and annotate it like this:
@Entity
@Table(name="TEST_TABLE")
public class TestEntity {

    /* many annotated fields */

    /* This field is mapping an Oracle's table column defined as BINARY_DOUBLE */
    @Column(name="DOUBLE_VALUE", columnDefinition="binary_double")
    @Type(type = "org.jpatests.model.types.BinaryDoubleType")
    private BinaryDouble doubleValue;

    /* more annotated fields */

}

With this code, any Java double, or Double, value will be written and read from any Oracle table column defined as being of binary_double type, even special values like Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, or Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY.
